# What is the difference between verify(exactly = 0) and wasNot Called in Mockk?

Tags: kotlin, mockk

What is the difference between using `verify(exactly = 0)` and using `wasNot called` assertions of MockK when testing Kotlin?

I have an example where the former passes the test but the latter yields:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: KLogger(#1).error(any())) was not called.
```

Code sample:

```
private val logger = mockk<KLogger>()
...
@Test
fun `logMessage should log message with info log level`() {
...
every { logger.info(logMessage) } just runs
...
verify(exactly = 1) { logger.info(logMessage) }
verify { logger.error(any<String>()) wasNot Called }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking if a function on the mock was called or not, `verify` must be used based on [this comment](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/349#issuecomment-537217312):

> Construction like verify { mock wasNot Called } is used not for
> function but for whole mock

This works correctly:

```
verify(exactly = 0) { logger.error(any<String>()) }
```